# Why should I use four backslash to render 2 backslash?

Tags: support, markdown

Today I was giving an answer to which I was quoting the following (without any change)

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as 
>   !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must
>   be escaped with with two backslashes: \. For example, an element with
>   id="foo.bar", can use the selector $("#foo\.bar").

You can see that I've used two backslash but there appears only one. This can be made into two, by including extra two backslashes.

So, 
`\\` produces `\`

`\\\\` produces `\\`

Comment: alternatively you could use code-highlight for this. IIRC the escaping is done for you inside of backticks.

Comment: As a programmer, this behaviour should not come as a surprise to you.

Comment: @awe I wasn't *surprised* I just didn't knew this existed..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is not a bug, but is part of Markdown, by design. Backslashes are normally used to *escape* Markdown markup, so you can include *asterisks* around text for example.

That last part is written as:

```
so you can include \*asterisks\* around text for example.
```

So to include a literal backslash in your text, not part of a inline code example (such as `code with \ backslash`), you need to double the \ backslash character.

Also see the [Markdown specification on escaping](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#backslash), linked from the [editing help documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help):

> Markdown provides backslash escapes for the following characters:
>
> ```
> \   backslash
> `   backtick
> *   asterisk
> _   underscore
> {}  curly braces
> []  square brackets
> ()  parentheses
> #   hash mark
> +   plus sign
> -   minus sign (hyphen)
> .   dot
> !   exclamation mark
> ```